# Devexpress PopupContainerEdit popup always open

Tags: winforms, c#-3.0, devexpress

Im'm using winform DevExpress library.
Now need to create a control, basing on PopupContainerEdit but this control must have some behaviors like when it's focused, the popup opens and when lost focus the popup closes.

This is the code I'm using but the popup dessapears after getting focus.

```
public class HelpEdit : PopupContainerEdit {
    private PopupContainerControl _container;
    private GridControl _gridControl;
    private GridView _gridView;

    [DefaultValue("")]
    [DXCategory("Data")]
    [AttributeProvider(typeof(IListSource))]
    public object Datasource {
        get { return _gridControl.DataSource; }
        set { _gridControl.DataSource = value; }
    }

    public HelpEdit() : base() {
        _container = new PopupContainerControl();
        this.Properties.TextEditStyle = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.TextEditStyles.Standard;
        this._gridControl = new GridControl();
        this._gridControl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        this._gridView = new GridView(_gridControl);
        _container.Controls.Add(_gridControl);
        _container.Size = new Size(this.Width, 250);

        this.Properties.PopupControl = _container;
        this.Properties.PopupControl.Size = new Size(this.Width, 250);
    }
    protected override void OnGotFocus(EventArgs e) {
        base.OnGotFocus(e);
        this.ShowPopup();
    }
    protected override void OnLostFocus(EventArgs e) {
        base.OnLostFocus(e);
        this.ClosePopup();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your popup disappears because it closes by your code as soon as the popup container control(`_container`) got focus itself. You should not close popup within the OnLostFocus() override because the `base.OnLostFocus` method of `PopupContainerEdit` is already contains correct code for closing popup. Or close popup conditionally, using the following code:

```
protected override void OnLostFocus(EventArgs e) {
    if(IsPopupOpen && !EditorContainsFocus) 
        ClosePopup(PopupCloseMode.Immediate);
    base.OnLostFocus(e);
}
```